# Getting error deploying functions: "Could not detect language for functions"

Tags: firebase, github, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

locally, and did "firebase init", etc. And everything works fine, and I can deploy it locally fine with no problems.

To get it deploy on GitHub, I set up a job with the following:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@11.17.0
python -m venv functions/venv
source functions/venv/bin/activate
python -m pip install -r functions/requirements.txt
firebase deploy --non-interactive
```

Once I get to deploy, however, I get this error:

```
[...]
functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
functions: preparing codebase default for deployment

Error: Could not detect language for functions at /home/runner/work/proj/proj/functions
```

I have tried a new version of Firebase as well, but that gives me a different error:

```
Error: Failed to find location of Firebase Functions SDK. Did you forget to run '. "/home/runner/work/CloudSite-Backend-/CloudSite-Backend-/functions/venv/bin/activate" && python3.11 -m pip install -r requirements.txt'?
```

Which obviously I did run, but it still gives me that error. This is why I switched to a older version.

Any help here with this?

Comment: firebase deploy --only functions

Comment: @JohnHanley I get the same error with that

Comment: Please don't edit answers into questions. Post them as answers below, so you can mark the answer as "accepted".